# Make the header image fit the container, nothing seems to work

Tags: html, css, html-helper

Nothing seems to be working for me. But what I would like to do is make the header image fit to the size I'd like, which is the container. Heres the actual page link: [this](http://zor-the-roleplay-helper.tumblr.com/definitions). 
And heres the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zorabelle/f7DRh/.

I think this is what I have to fix but I just don't know.

```
/*HEADER IMAGE DETAILS - HEADER MUST BE 921PX WIDE*/
.header {
        background-image: url(http://media.tumblr.com/aceb30d864925524ee215c0d6f88e1bc/tumblr_inline_mu0br62w4R1s7znag.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:200px; /*CHANGE TO THE HEIGHT OF YOUR BANNER*/
        }
```

I want the 'Define the Term' header to fill up that whole space. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/f7DRh/2/

You can set the image size to container by specifying:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

That way it will always keep it within container's width and height.

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the traditional  replacing your div

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="upcon">
    <img src="http://yourimage.com" style="width:100%" />
</div>
```

By the way, with this method the browser tries to render the image correctly if the user has a resoltion smaller than what your are asking (1050px). It won't crop it.